# iOs is not updating on my iPod Touch - how can I fix it?

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch (8gb) which currently has iOS 4.2.1.  I thought the latest version was 4.3, but it's not upgrading.  When I go to iTunes, I click on 'Check for update' and it says I have the latest version.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the new version just not available for my iPod?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 4.2.1 is the latest available version for 2G iPod Touches.

Comment: Thanks!  Are they likely to introduce iOS 4.3 for 2G, do you know?  Like, do they just stop at a certain point?  There's a game I'd love to play, but it's only available for 4.3!

Comment: iOS 4.3 was released in March 2011, so at this point, it seems unlikely it will become available to more devices. Sorry. Try contacting the game developer and ask if they can support an older OS.

Comment: No chance, I'm afraid, as they want you to get a new device. Don't be too depressed, though - I'm stuck on iOS 3 as I have a 1G iPod Touch!